# Erro na comparação de matrizes

Tags: c

A questão pede uma comparação de matrizes,tentei compara-las, só que a resposta se são iguais aparece varias vezes e não sei como solucionar esse prolema, é o que está causando os 10% de erro que o uri está informando.

[Aqui o link](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1383) para a questão

O meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i, j, teste, a;
int main()
{
  int matriz[9][9] = {{1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8},
                        {4, 9, 8, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 5},
                        {7, 5, 6, 3, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9},
                        {6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 8, 7, 9, 2},
                        {5, 2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 8, 4, 6},
                        {9, 8, 7, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 1},
                        {2, 1, 4, 9, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7},
                        {3, 6, 5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2, 4},
                        {8, 7, 9, 6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3}
                    }, sudoku[9][9];

    scanf("%d", &teste);
    for(a = 0; a < teste; a++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &sudoku[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                if(matriz[i][j] != sudoku[i][j])
                {
                    printf("Instancia %d\n", a + 1);
                    printf("NAO\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Instancia %d\n", a + 1);
                    printf("SIM\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é isso o que a questão pede. Do enunciado: "Na segunda linha, seu programa deverá imprimir "SIM" se a matriz for a solução de um problema de Sudoku, e "NAO" caso contrário"

Comment: olha eu fiz assim criei uma matriz que contém a resposta correta,assim que o usuário digitar,vou comparar o que o usuário digitou  com a resposta correta,se as matrizes forem iguais vai receber sim,caso contrario recebe não,teria outra solução para esse problema?

Comment: Da uma lida melhor sobre Matrizes em C, e evite usar mais que 2 for, use funções, pois seu código esta inelegível.

Answer (score 0):

É mostrada a resposta varias vezes porque ela está dentro do laço, você deveria mudar para guardar o resultado em uma flag e perguntar fora do laço (segundo grupo de laços), assim:

```
//  Continua no laço enquanto encontrar valores iguais.
bool bIguais = true;
for(i = 0; i < 9 && bIguais; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 9 && bIguais; j++)
    {
        bIguais = matriz[i][j] != sudoku[i][j];
    }
}

if(bIguais)
{
    printf("Instancia %d\n", a + 1);
    printf("NAO\n\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Instancia %d\n", a + 1);
    printf("SIM\n\n");
}
```